# Hit URL using VB.NET (Get and Forget)

Tags: vb.net, url, get, hit, fire-and-forget

I want to create get and forget Url using vb.net. Basically I will push an url(just get response from url, not showing in the browser/run in background) and forget. I want push 10 url at the same time when I the button clicked. Here's my code, but it still processing the url the url one by one.

I have tried using Task, but I got an error when including "Imports System.Threading.Tasks" because my .net framework version still 3.5.
It is impossible to upgrade my .Net version, so is anyone have an advice?

Please let me know what should I do, thanks before :)

Comment: Hi, were's your code? And.. yes you can upgrade your .net version... after upgrade you can choose what .net  version your app uses from app's properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular threads for this sort of thing.  My VB.Net is very rusty.  Here's approximately what I would do in C#.  It should translate directly to VB.Net

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

foreach (string url in MyUrls)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => MyUrlPushMethod(url));
    t.Start();
    threads.Add(t);
}

foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```